# Shopify variant purchase to decrease total number of products

Tags: events, shopify, product-quantity

Bit of an unusual one this but hopefully someone has tackled this before.

I've got a client who is an events venue, they sell tickets at a maximum of 200 people for each time slot. This is for a regular weekend day, however sometimes they host events on these days which are a different price to the standard tickets.

So for example there's a 200 person limit, regular ticket price £5, with an event going on with price of £10. They need it to work that if either a £5 or £10 ticket is bought, the 200 quantity remaining is decreased... is that possible in Shopify natively? It seems like you have to set quantities for each variant option which are separate to each other.

Comment: If by "natively" you mean without app, the answer is no. But there are plenty of apps for events.

Comment: @FabioFilippi Is there no way to decrease the quantity of a variant if another variant is purchased? Like sending a POST after a customer goes through the checkout

Comment: You can't send a call after checkout and there is no Ajax api to decrease the stock quantity. 
The only native solution that I can think of is to have just one variant but using line item properties. The same functionality to use when you have a customizable product. That would require a bit of work on the theme but is possible.

Comment: Another way could be to have one variant for the ticket and another product/variants for any "extra". The first variant is linked to the stock the second is not.